# xamarin.forms webview baseurl not working on device (iOS 10.1)

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin.forms app that uses HybridWebView (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/hybridwebview/) to display an html document. I use baseUrl to load local css and js into the document. This code was working fine on iOS 9.x.

But, after I upgraded to iOS 10, the code works on the iOS simulator but not on the actual device. On the device, it does not load the css from local storage.

here is the test code I am using. It works on simulator but not on device.

```
    async void Handle_TestButtonClicked (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string css = @"
            body {
                background-color: powderblue;
            }
            h1 {
                color: blue;
            }
            p {
                color: red;
            }
            ";
        var folder = await AppGlobals.AppStorage.GetContentFolder ();
        string filename = "styles.css";
        await AppGlobals.AppStorage.WriteToFile (folder, filename, css);

        string html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
                        <html>
                        <head>
                          <link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""styles.css"">
                        </head>
                        <body>

                        <h1>This is a heading</h1>
                        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

                        </body>
                        </html>";

        this.DocumentView.Html = html;
    }
```

In the HybridWebView, I am using the following code to set the baseUrl

```
            if (Element.Html != null) {
                string baseFolderPath = await AppStorage.GetInstance ().GetContentFolderPath ();
                var baseUrl = new NSUrl (baseFolderPath, true);
                Control.LoadHtmlString (Element.Html, baseUrl);
            }
```

I am using PCLStorage library to read/write to local storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think LoadHtmlString is broken for loading local css/js etc.

I worked around this problem by writing the HTML string to local file and then loading it using LoadFileUrl. This works as expected

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty (Element.Uri)) {
                    string filePath = await GetFilePathInContentFolderFromUri (Element.Uri);
                    var fileUrl = new NSUrl (filePath, false);
                    Control.LoadFileUrl (fileUrl, fileUrl);
                }
```

Another work-around could be to inject the required css/js into the html document itself and still use LoadHtmlString, this works.

Comment: It's fascinating how i am facing this issue after 7 years! 
for the other workaround, what about images? i guess i can convert them to base64 but this will be alot of work